# Unable to plot a graph starting from origin (0, 0) with matplotlib in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I want to plot a graph in Jupyter Notebook by using `matplotlib` but my graphs are showing something like this:

[image]

My `x-axis` values are not starting exactly at the origin. I want the graph line to start at `(0, 0)`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add a [mcve].

Comment: Then you need to include that point in the data you send to the plot command.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that your source data is held in a *pandasonic* DataFrame
like this:

```
  Test Cases  fault courage
0        TC1              6
1        TC2              7
2        TC3              6
3        TC4              8
4        TC5             10
5        TC6             10
6        TC7              5
7        TC8             10
```

so somewhere earlier your code should include:

```
import pandas as pd
```

In order to include the "initial" (zero) point in your plot,
you have to create an auxiliary DataFrame with this "zero row"
placed as the first position. You can do it e.g. running:

```
wrk = pd.concat(
    [pd.DataFrame([{'Test Cases': '', 'fault courage': 0}]), df],
    ignore_index=True)
```

Print *wrk* to see the result.

Then, to generate your wanted image, run:

```
plt.fill_between(wrk['Test Cases'], 0, wrk['fault courage'])
plt.show()
```

The result is:

[image]

If you want any *x* label for the first point, put it in *Test Cases* column
of the prepended DataFrame (I put there an empty string).

## Edit

I forgot about axis labels. To add them, add:

```
plt.xlabel('Test Cases')
plt.ylabel('fault courage')
```

before `plt.show()`.

Comment: when I run this code as you mentioned, I encounter an error "None of [Index(['TC6', 'TC4', 'TC1', 'TC2', 'TC3', 'TC5', 'TC7', 'TC8'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Comment: I suppose that your DataFrame (*df*) differs in some respect from the source DataFrame that I created to test my code. Create the source DaaFrame just the way I shown. Your error message suggests that your DataFrame has *Test Cases* as columns, so maybe you should start from transposing it. This is the conseuence of the fact that you failed to show the content of your source DataFrame.